# Jagged array in Rust

Tags: rust

I want a buffer for messages of variant length.
`Vec<String>` or in my case `Vec<Vec<u8>>` works perfectly but I don't want to allocate separate memory for each message. I'd much rather reuse and utilize a single big buffer.

I am pretty sure implementation for such thing already exists, so my question is - where can I find it? Is there any crate providing such container?

I made my own implementation for such structure, there's a test so you can see what I'm expecting from it:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PushVec<T: Clone> {
    buffer: Vec<T>,
    slices: Vec<usize>,
}

impl<T: Clone> PushVec<T> {
    pub fn push(&mut self, data: &[T]) {
        let len = data.len();
        self.buffer.extend_from_slice(data);
        self.slices.push(len);
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> {
        let mut bytes_counter: usize = 0;
        self.slices.iter().map(move |slice_len| {
            let slice = &self.buffer[bytes_counter .. bytes_counter + slice_len];
            bytes_counter += slice_len;
            slice
        })
    }

    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.slices.clear();
        self.buffer.clear();
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::PushVec;

    #[test]
    fn multi_vec_test() { 
        let mut multi = PushVec::<i32>::default();
        multi.push(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
        multi.push(&[8, 9]);
        multi.push(&[10, 11]);

        let get_result: Vec<&[i32]> = multi.iter().collect();
        assert_eq!(get_result[0], &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
        assert_eq!(get_result[1], &[8, 9]);
        assert_eq!(get_result[2], &[10, 11]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use `Vec<&[u8]>` then? Why do you need the inner values to be `Vec`?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I don't think there's anything you could do to improve it without a specific application.

Comment: The only improvement I would suggest is to use a `Vec<(usize, usize)>` for the `slices` field in order to enable `O(1)` access to arbitrary items.

Comment: @cdhowie Imagine you get messages as JSON string, but you poll IO only once in a while. I can't toss all messages into `Vec<&[u8]>` because many single JSON objects is invalid JSON, until closed in an array. So instead, I want a buffer that holds individual messages, but in a single big buffer.

Comment: @cafce25 It's a pretty simple structure, and very widely used see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
[Datazoo](https://crates.io/crates/datazoo) has been updated with new features, I will use this one.

---

After consulting `bevy` Discord I found out what I am looking for is [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).
There are two crates I found that implement it:

- https://crates.io/crates/datazoo
- https://docs.rs/jagged_array/latest/jagged_array/

However both seem to have interface matching their creators needs at the time. I was hoping there'd be a much more "generic" implementation that you could use out of the box for everything you can dream of, just like `std` containers are made, but seems like it's not the case.

So I guess my solution for this is to stay with my own implementation and make it suit my individual needs as well.